How to get IP address in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project
I am creating an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project and trying to fetch IP address with this code:
var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

But, the code throws an exception:

Address = 'remoteIpAddress.Address' threw an exception of type System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Please help me to solve this.
I tried to update the code but I am not able to fix it.

What's the full exception message and stacktrace?

Area you trying to get IP from your backend or get IP from client side also okay ? Because sometimes, RemoteIpAddress will get you only ::1 so if you send the request form client side that would be easy.

U can try this :
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress


There is not HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET Core


How to get IP address in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project

In order to get client-Ip-address we could implement couple of ways. But as I told you earlier using RemoteIpAddress sometimes give you improper octave like this ::1.
I have retrieved IP using various ways, however, using fetch('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json') API get me the more accuracy.
What I did is, whoever, visits the application, I have called above endpoint, and bind the IP in http request as a request header so if I check the request header I would get the user Ip after that.
I have my own middleware, where, I am checking context.Request and I have set the IP as cookie header like this document.cookie = clientIpAddress=${data.ip};`
I can simply bind the IP before sending any ajax request as well but I have done this way so that IP would be avaiable in httpContext, thus, I can get that in every http context wherever I would need it.
Let's have a look in practice, how we can implement that:
Middleware:
public class IpAddressMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public IpAddressMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("clientIpAddress", out var clientIp))
        {
            context.Items["ClientIp"] = clientIp;// Can be set anywhere you need in the context
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

Javascript should integrate within the application index/landing page:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    async function fetchIpAddress() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json');
            const data = await response.json();
            document.cookie = `clientIpAddress=${data.ip}; path=/`;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching IP address:', error);
        }
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
        const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
        const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
        if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }

    $(document).ready(async function () {
        await fetchIpAddress();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                const clientIpAddress = getCookie('clientIpAddress');
                if (clientIpAddress) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Client-IP', clientIpAddress);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    
</script>

Note: As you can notice, beforeSend: function (xhr) also used if you want to extract the IP from your ajax request, its up to your preference.
Get IP from anywhere using following code:
var checkContext = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("ClientIp", out var userIpAddress);
var userIp = userIpAddress;

Output:




Note: Keep in mind, its absolutely, programmers call, how they want to consume the user Ip-Address, I found this hassle free. You can  bind the IP when you would submit the request to your controller, if you don't want to bind in cookie or other place so that would also okay. Once again its a programmer preference.
